# Update multiple raspberry pi with single image

Tags: raspberry-pi, upgrade

I am working on a project which I need to update 10 raspberry pi images with the latest image which i modify some files and directories and install some packages on it. I am working on one raspberry pi and I want clone its image to all 9 other RPIs. my boards use raspian OS and I do not use custom iamge. Is there any solution for such situation?